# What are the names of my network adapters? (Vagrant related)

Tags: networking, virtualbox, bridge, vagrant

I'm trying to use mVagrant to set up a bridge on the correct network adapter.

I keep getting this message:

> Specific bridge 'Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection' not
>   found. You may be asked to specify

Using `ipconfig` on the host machine (Windows), I found these:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:
```

Are these the names of the host adapter adapters that I can choose? If so, my host machine is connected via wifi right now so isn't the second one "Wireless LAN..." the correct choice for the host adapter?

More context: In [the Vagrant documentation](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/public_network.html), I was told to choose the host adapter I wanted to bridge:

> If more than one network interface is available on the host machine, Vagrant will ask you to choose which interface the virtual machine should bridge to. A default interface can be specified by adding a :bridge clause to the network definition.

Here is what I have in Vangrantfile:

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "10.0.1.99", bridge: "Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection"
```

Answer (score 12):

In Windows it's a bit messy.

What you want to do is to use `VBoxManage.exe list bridgedifs` to list the possible bridge interface names (the actual names are device names, not connection names which you see in `ipconfig` output)

VBoxManage is probably not in your `%PATH%` but you can find it in Virtualbox's dir.

You also can just copy the device name from Connection Properties in Control Panel.

Comment: I had to use `vboxmanage list bridgedifs` in OSX to get the desired interface names. `ifconfig` does not print the full interface names. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note it's NOT the 'Network' name in VirtualBox manager.

Comment: If you have `git bash` installed, you can edit your `~/.bashrc` file and add this alias so that you can use `vboxmanage` without the full path: `alias vboxmanage='C:\\Program\ Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\vboxmanage.exe'`